# Connect component not rendering props correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a bit of an issue with Redux, as I'm trying to wrap my with connect(). Consider all imports valid(as they are). Here's the source code along with the output error. [image: bad error :((]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect, bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux'
import * as counterActionCreators from '../core/actionCreators/count'

class CounterEgg extends Component {
  render() {
    const { onIncrement, store } = this.props
    let { value } = this.props
    value = store.getState()

    return (
      <div>
        Clicked: {value} times
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onIncrement: bindActionCreators(counterActionCreators, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterEgg);
```

Comment: I'm using webpack 2.0, FWIW

Comment: I'm also subscribing the store through provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your import is actually *not* valid:

`import { connect, bindActionCreators } from 'react-redux'`

`bindActionCreators` is part of `redux`, not `react-redux`.

So you should have

`import { connect } from 'react-redux'`

`import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'`

Comment: Thanks U r s u s !